# Подскажите метод в java android, который бы открывал и воспроизводил видеофайлы в моем плеере?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Я начинающий программист в области java на андроид. пишу сейчас приложение на андроид - видеоплеер. Вообщем столкнулся с таким проблемой, неделю уже мучаюсь. Меню создан, метод, который находит видеофайлы есть, но когда нажимаю на файл, плеер сворачивается. Нужна помощь в написании метода, который бы воспроизводил выбранный файл в моем плеере т.е. на данном этапе в своем плеере, чтобы просмотреть галерею файлов, но при нажатии на файл приложение сворачивается.

```
    public class VideoPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView SMPlayer;
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayer";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.SMPlayer);


    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();



}


//** метод продолжает видео при повороте экрана
int videoPosition = 0;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    videoPosition = SMPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    outState.putInt("Position", videoPosition);
    Log.d("My_Log", "onSaveInstanceState = " + videoPosition);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    videoPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    Log.d("My_Log", "onRestoreInstanceState = " + videoPosition);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.smmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
//** обработка нажатий
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.action_open){
        Intent openFileIntent= null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        }
        assert openFileIntent != null;
        openFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        openFileIntent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(openFileIntent,READ_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
protected void onActivityResult(int reguestCode, int resultCode, int showVideo, Intent data){
    if(reguestCode== READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri currentOpenFileUri = null;
        if(data != null){
            currentOpenFileUri = data.getData();
            assert currentOpenFileUri != null;
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + currentOpenFileUri.toString());
            showVideo(Uri);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Давай по порядку. У тебя есть приложение, которое отображает список файлов для воспроизведения, а также воспроизводит их по нажатию на файл из списка? При нажатии на файл приложение "сворачивается" или по сути вылетает. Тогда смотри почему вылетает, например через android monitor.

Comment: Я может не правильно вопрос сформулировал. Вообщем открываю плеер, нажимаю на кнопку открыть, появляется галерея с видеофайлами, хранящимися на телефоне, я нажимаю на файл и мое приложение сворачивается. Я не знаю как дописать код, чтобы при нажатии видео воспроизводилось.